# How to Turn off Grizzly Logging?

Tags: java, logging, server, grizzly

How can I turn off the Logging of Grizzly?

I'd like to turn off following Loggings:

```
Okt 18, 2018 8:42:24 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFORMATION: Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]
Okt 18, 2018 8:42:24 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFORMATION: [HttpServer] Started.
```

Thanks in advance for any help/ advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an own solution - I did everything by reflection:

```
    Enumeration<String> loggers = LogManager.getLogManager().getLoggerNames();
    while (loggers.hasMoreElements()) {
        String loggerName = loggers.nextElement();
        if(loggerName.contains("glassfish")) {
            Logger logger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(loggerName);
            logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);     
        }
    }
```

Consider that this will turn off all glassfish-Loggings.